# (AndroidStudio y GoogleDRIVE) Como subir un archivo a la nube desde Android

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, google-drive

bueno les cuento el problema/idea, el tema es que yo tengo un programa que genera muchos archivo(en un determinado intervalo de tiempo) .csv(similares a .txt) los cuales tienen información almacenada, el tema es que quiero poder luego de que se creen poder subirlos(idealmente a google drive pero podria ser otra nube), lo cual trae el problema que no se como subirlos. He leido la información sobre el tema pero no la estoy entendiendo.

```java
else{
                                Log.i("sensor","No existe aun elemento"+ n);

                                texto=findViewById(R.id.Estado);
                                texto.setText("FOS "+n);

                                fos = openFileOutput(n+".csv", MODE_PRIVATE);

                                Log.i("sensor","InicioFOS "+n);



                                task.getResult().setEnvironment(0, fos);

                                sensor.temperatura().start();
                                sensor.start();
                                Thread.sleep(10000);

                                sensor.stop();
                                sensor.temperatura().stop();
                                fos.close();
```

El archivo que se crea la idea es que se suba luego del fos.close() 
La verdad no tengo idea de como hacerlo pero seria de gran ayuda que alguien me explicara.

Comment: Google tenía o tiene una API específica para el manejo de Drive en Android, pero OJO, esa API es obsoleta y ahora hay que usar la REST API. En la [documentación hay ejemplos en código Java](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads) para subir archivos. Claro está, tendrás que configurar la REST API y preparar tu proyecto Android para tener acceso a ella. Está todo explicado allí. Intenta y dinos cómo te ha ido o qué errores tienes.

Comment: Donde esta el texto que quieres en el CSV?

Comment: el texto Es obtenido de unos sensores